# CSS Gradient - Chrome - icky vertical stripe

Tags: google-chrome, css

[image]

I've got these CSS buttons that use gradients generated by http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ - the :hover state simply reverses the gradient, active state adds top: 1px;

As you can see in the image, there is a faint vertical stripe on the left edge of the 'free trial' button and on the right edge of the 'buy now' button.

This only shows up in Chrome (looks fine in Safari). Is anyone aware of a fix for this?

I've got some CSS below

```
.big-button {
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.big-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.big-button-wrap .big-button:active {
    top: 7px !important;
}

.big-button.orange {
    background: #fe7d0a; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #fda11a 0%, #ff6801 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fda11a), color-stop(100%,#ff6801)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #fda11a 0%,#ff6801 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #fda11a 0%,#ff6801 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #fda11a 0%,#ff6801 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #fda11a 0%,#ff6801 100%); /* W3C */
    border: 1px solid #ff6801;
}
.big-button.orange:hover, .big-button.orange:active {
    background: #fe7d0a; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ff6801 0%, #fda11a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff6801), color-stop(100%,#fda11a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ff6801 0%,#fda11a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ff6801 0%,#fda11a 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ff6801 0%,#fda11a 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  #ff6801 0%,#fda11a 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

Comment: Can you post the associated HTML or better yet, create a jsFiddle?

Comment: It might be worth checking that it actually is the gradients causing the stripe. Does the problem go away if you set a solid color on the buttons?

Comment: fiddle added here: http://jsfiddle.net/QAafv/ - Notice the stripe shows up on hover and disappears if you mouse down on the button. It does appear as though its the border-radius causing it, not the gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding ***border-left:none;*** for ***.big-button.orange:hover*** and ***border-right:none;*** for the green removed the lines for me in the fiddle (using Chrome).

Here's my CSS:

```
.big-button.orange:hover, .big-button.orange:active {
background: #fe7d0a; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ff6801 0%, #fda11a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ff6801), color-stop(100%,#fda11a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ff6801 0%,#fda11a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ff6801 0%,#fda11a 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ff6801 0%,#fda11a 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top,  #ff6801 0%,#fda11a 100%); /* W3C */
border-left:none;
```

}

```
.big-button.green:hover, .big-button.green:active {
background: #6a9a23; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #558711 0%, #8cb941 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#558711), color-stop(100%,#8cb941)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #558711 0%,#8cb941 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #558711 0%,#8cb941 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #558711 0%,#8cb941 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(top,  #558711 0%,#8cb941 100%); /* W3C */
border-right:none;
```

}​

Comment: Ah perfect... I swear I had tried adding 'border: none;' but I must have just been on the wrong element. Thanks kindly.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your css and couldn't recreate the problem. It looks like it might be the wrapper around the two buttons which has the problem?

Try making the gradients applied to 'background-image' rather than 'background' (they normally are).